# Wolfram population density demonstration does not appear to work

Tags: plotting, geography, demonstrations

I tried to do the [Wolfram population density demonstration](http://www.wolfram.com/language/gallery/map-population-distributions/) and it returned an error:

```
GeoRegionValuePlot[Entity["AdministrativeDivision",{_,"Texas","UnitedStates"}]->"Population"]

GeoRegionValuePlot::reps: Missing[UnknownEntity,{AdministrativeDivision,{_,Texas,UnitedStates}}]->Missing[Propagated,Missing[UnknownEntity,{AdministrativeDivision,{_,Texas,UnitedStates}}]] is not a list of rules of the form loc -> val >>
GeoRegionValuePlot[Entity[AdministrativeDivision,{_,Texas,UnitedStates}]->Population]
```

How can I get it to work?

Comment: I suspect your `Entity` was obtained in an odd way, perhaps from a cut and paste? It doesn't seem to be anything other than a string of text, i.e. dataless.

Comment: How should I get the Entity? I just copied the text from the example on the web page (as linked).

Comment: I have communicated with WRI about this entity wildcard functionality; it is broken in many places. You could get them via `GeoEntities[
 Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Texas", "UnitedStates"}], "AdministrativeDivision"]`

Comment: That's odd they use it that way in the link, I can't recreate their output of that command in v10.2. However, using `AdministrativeDivisionData[{"Texas", "UnitedStates"}, 
   "Subdivisions"]` I'm able to get the list of divisions in Texas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I cannot get the code in the demonstration to work either (MMA 10.2 on Win7-64).

A possible workaround might be to obtain a list of all the administrative divisions known to MMA, then selecting the ones in Texas, and applying `GeoRegionValuePlot` to those, as shown below:

```
alladmindivs = EntityList["AdministrativeDivision"];
GeoRegionValuePlot[
 Cases[alladmindivs, 
   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {_, "Texas", "UnitedStates"}], Infinity] -> "Population"
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

The following alternative method is based on It'sPronouncedOiler's suggestion in the comments to use `AdministrativeDivisionData`. It produces the same plot as the one above.

```
GeoRegionValuePlot[
   AdministrativeDivisionData[{"Texas", "UnitedStates"}, "Subdivisions"] -> "Population"]
```

---

It is worth noting, however, that neither method reproduces the plot shown in the linked demonstration...

Comment: Does the `AdministrativeDivisionData` alternative you provided work in your version? I had used that exact input in v10.2 but it produced a plot with almost half the municipals missing. I double checked it now after a kernel restart and it's still missing municipals, but different ones so maybe it's a rendering issue.

Comment: @It'sPronouncedOiler Yes it seems to work as well as the other one, or possibly better because I only had to download the Texas ad hoc information, rather than a list of all the administrative divisions. Here is the plot it produces: [`AdministrativeDivisionData` plot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RG6sk.png).